# ELMAH get user info from request in anonymous website

Tags: asp.net, .net, elmah, asp.net-4.5

I'm using ELMAH to log errors for ASP.Net website with anonymous access. Because of this, the "user" in the log is blank and I want to populate with information from the Request. I get the user info in the request header of the page and I want pass that information to ELMAH so that it can record the current user.  I tried using `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(UserInfo.UserName, true);` but it still showing up blank in the log.

Thanks in advance.